# Where does the word 完美 come from?

Tags: etymology

I suspect it comes from "又做完了，又做得美丽," since that would make some sense. Is it something along these lines?

Comment: it seems simply to be a matter of adverb 完 qualifying adjective 美, cf. 完好，完满，完善、完整, of course 完
can modify adverbs (e.g. 完全）or verbs also （e。g。完毕）

Comment: 完 means `to complete`, `sound and safe`, `to be ready`, `a reunion`

Comment: I don't think 完 here means "finish, end", it should be the same meaning as in "完璧归赵", it's "complete, whole".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there's an earlier usage of "完美" in 唐 dynasty. in 漢文大藏經﹒毗尼作持續釋﹒卷五:

釋　若犯妄語。譬如大石破為二分終不可還合者。謂石大　**完美**　。四覩奇觀。比丘戒淨。人天欽仰。若犯妄語波羅夷法。不得還成比丘梵行。布薩羯磨不共眾僧。如石兩分。破壞本質。失眾敬瞻。棄置不盻故。

http://tripitaka.cbeta.org/mobile/index.php?index=X41n0730_005

so, i would suggest the etymology of "完美" is derived from "完整" + "美好"

[image]

Comment: Sorry if this is obvious from your excerpt, but how do you know that the 完美 comes from "完整" + "美好"?

Comment: the metaphor of 犯妄語 is 大石破為二分 --> a big rock is broken into two halves. so 守戒 (not 犯妄語) is a whole, complete big rock. that, "完整" matched. next, "美好" is the most common term suitable for describing rock. anyway, it's just a suggestion for explaining 完美 in this buddhism text. have fun :)

Answer (score 0):

**完**(adverbial - **entirely / wholly**) + **美**(adjective - **beautiful / excellent**)

**完美** is a compound word for "perfect, perfectly, perfection"

> **完** http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/characters/880/
>
> |jyun4|  jyutping
>
> |wan2 |  pinyin
>
> [1] [v] complete; finish; bring to a conclusion
>
> [2] **whole**
>
> [3] [v] run out; use up
>
> [4] a Chinese family name
>
> **美** http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/characters/257/
>
> |mei5|  jyutping
>
> |mei3|   pinyin
>
> [1] beautiful; pretty; pleasing; fine; fair
>
> [2] good; **excellent**; exquisite; nice
>
> [3] be pleased with oneself
>
> [4] [v] praise
>
> **完美** http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/9672/
>
> |jyun4 mei5|   jyutping
>
> |wan2 mei3|   pinyin
>
> **perfect**, perfection, perfectly

Answer (score 0):

宋 司马光 《太子太保庞公墓志铭》：“至於庐舍饮食，无不尽心为之驱处，使皆完美”。这是我索到的“完美”一词最早的出处。完在古代汉语可作形容词，意思是完整的，完好的，如完璧归赵。在司马光的文章中“完美”一词应是完备美好之意。至于完美一词什么时候变成现代汉语中“完美”(perfect)的意思，这个我就不清楚了。